# material UI styeled components how to apply style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design, styled-components

Styled with styled = components using MaterialUI
The following error appears in LoginTextField.
I don't know how to solve it.

**errormessage**
[ts] Type '{ width: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick & Partial<...>, "label" | ... 283 more ... | "width">': style, ref, className, onFocus, and 7 more. [2740]

**enviroment**
Typescript ,
React.js(Hooks),
Material UI,
styled-component,

```
// styleButton.tsx
import { Button,TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const LoginTextField = styled(TextField)<{ width: number }>`
  width: ${(props) => props.width};
`
```

```
// index.tsx
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { LoginTextField } from "../components/styleButton"

export const Login: FC = () => {

return (
<LoginTextField width={600}></ LoginTextField>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead for styleButton.tsx

```
import { Button, TextField, TextFieldProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";

//type aliases 
type StyledTextFieldProps = TextFieldProps && { width: number };

export const LoginTextField = styled(TextField)`
   width: ${(props: StyledTextFieldProps) => props.width} 
` as React.ComponentType<StyledTextFieldProps>;
```

Comment: Tank you.  　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
I tried it above but couldn't.   　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　erromessage  ```
ts] 'number' refers only to a type, but is used here as a value. [2693]  
Property 'width' does not exist in type 'TextFieldProps'.
  Property 'width' does not exist in type 'StandardTextFieldProps'. [2339]```